# How do I get libpam.so.0 (32 bit) on my 64bit RHEL6?

Tags: linux, db2, redhat

I am trying to install DB2 Enterprise Server on my RHEL6 machine. Unfortunately, it seems that it needs the 32bit version of libpam.so.0 for some routines. The machine runs the 64 bit version which seems to have the lib installed... I assume it's the 64 version.
Is there any way to get and install the 32 bit version to be used by the DB2 installer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is probably related, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21573357

seems you need to install pam-1.1.1-10.el6.i686.rpm

Comment: 'yum install pam.i686' will work even when the versions have changed.

Comment: `yum install pam-devel` is what i needed

Answer (score 9):

yum install pam.i686 is what you should enter into the command line.

Comment: Yay, thanks! Don't forget the `-y` argument to yum so that it won't ask silly questions (or, more importantly in my case, so you can automate it easily.)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to install the package `libpam.so.0`, which represents the 32-bit version of libpam:

```sh
yum install libpam.so.0
```

This is mentioned on the Db2 LUW V11.1 documentation,
on Table 1. Package requirements for SLES and RHEL distributions:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=servers-linux#r0008865__t-sles-rhel

Comment: Gracias Carlos, me has salvado la vida